# How easy is Android development?

Tags: android

I am absolutely new to Android and am a little scared as I look uphill at the task of assimilating the entirely new world of Android. I am very good with C++, Java, Javascript and the world of browsers. How difficult is it going to be to learn Android development? Can somebody point me to a good way to begin? - a book or some sort of an online guide would be great.

Comment: click on the android tag for a list of resources. As for "how easy it is" - that's completely subjective. voted to close.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I would ask the community their opinion on this. I am pretty swamped I think.

Comment: this is not the right site for that kind of discussion.

Comment: Just read the Google Android developers guide, if you say you are good at java you should be able to develop Android in a week or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the android dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

If you are good with java, you will have no issues

Answer (score 2):

[This book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Android-3-Sayed-Hashimi/dp/1430232226/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303136246&sr=8-1) is one of the best reference currently available. It is the first covering Honeycomb. I have the first version and I'm really happy with it. Additionally, you may want to have a look at the [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Start with the google tutorials especially the [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)s.

Also the Google [dev guide's](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) are very good.